# Nginx rewrite and return interfere with different location block

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, 301-redirect, nginx-ingress

I have the following configuration in nginx for redirecting in a certain scenario.

```
location /prefix-someurl {
   if (condition) {
            return 301 $scheme://$host/xyz.html;
   }
   proxy_pass someValue;
}
```

and in another block there are some rewrite rules like this

```
location /someurl {
   if (condition) {
            rewrite ^(.*)abc(.*)$ $1test/abc$2 break;               
            rewrite ^(.*)someurl/$(.*) $1someurl/test/index.html$2;

   }
   proxy_pass value;
}
```

The above configuration works as intended. However if for the latter I make this modification;

```
location /someurl {
   if (condition) {
            return 301 $scheme://$host/xyz.html;
   }
   if (condition) {
            rewrite ^(.*)abc(.*)$ $1test/abc$2 break;               
            rewrite ^(.*)someurl/$(.*) $1someurl/test/index.html$2;

   }
   proxy_pass value;
}
```

I get too many redirect errors for accessing **`/prefix-someurl`**.If I modify the `/someurl` to the following the error goes away;

```
location /someurl {
  if (condition) {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/xyz.html;
  }    
  proxy_pass value;
}
```

I cannot understand why modifying `/someurl` has an impact on `/prefix-someurl`. Or am I missing something regarding nginx rewrite evaluation. Insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to identify each step in the loop. Use `curl -I` to test the individual redirects. Also, enable the [`rewrite_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log) to get diagnostics from the rewrite engine.

Comment: You can most likely find an answer at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ . Instead of `if`, you should use `map` and use another strategy for your conditions.